# iphoto versus imovie - wanting to get features from both places

Tags: photos.app, imovie

Origami is very nice. However, detailed control is, in my case, very hard to live without. I am setting up a 10-minute slide show. I want to use several pieces of audio cued to different points in the show. I want to have some sections, and origama shuffles my pictures across the section boundaries. Even text slides don't clue it in that this might be a good place not to shuffle across. Some of my consumers find the plain 'Ken Burns' transition in imovie positively sea-sickness-inducing.

I can predict that the answer will be that, inside iphoto, I'm in the traditional 'Steve Jobs is the reincarnation of Henry Ford' situation, and I won't be finding any way to exercise detailed control. So, can anyone give me a running start on how to introduce other transition effects to imovie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versions of iMovie after iMovie HD don't support plugins and extra effects.

You're looking for something more along the lines of [Apple Final Cut Express](http://www.apple.com/finalcutexpress/) ([$170](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Z3DXT2)) or [Adobe Premiere Elements](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiereel/) ([$80](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YV62CM)).

Both let you make photo slideshows with titles, effects, transitions, and music; and both let you install free and paid plugins for more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, then, It's time to turn this into 5 smaller shows in iPhoto, origami each one, export, import into imovie, and add music.